# How do I fix this (it is supposed to toggle 'toggle')

Tags: javascript

This is supposed to toggle between off and on with a click but won't go back to on. :(

I have tried true/false statements as well as `g--;` & `g++;`(or `g-=1;` & `g+=1;`)

```
    var toggle=true;
    var g = 1;
    draw=function() {
       if (mouseIsPressed&&g===1){
            toggle=true;
            g=2;
       }
       if (mouseIsPressed&&g===2) {
            toggle=false;
            g=1;
       }
       if(toggle===true){
            background(255, 255, 255);
            fill(255, 0, 255);
            text('('+ mouseX + ',' + mouseY+')',mouseX,mouseY);
        }
        if(toggle===false){
            background(255,255,255);
            text('(off)',mouseX,mouseY);
        }
    };
```

I was expecting it to toggle at a click but it is only staying at the second step.

Comment: The second `if` statement will always be `true`, because the first one sets `g=2`. I think you want `else if` instead.

Comment: What is `mouseIsPressed` and what fdo you think `&&` does to numbers?

Comment: `if (mouseIsPressed && toggle){
     toggle = false;
 } else {
    toggle = true;
 }`

Answer (score 3):

The second `if` statement will always be `true`, because the first one sets `g=2`. Here is a simplified example:

```js
var mouseIsPressed = true;
var g = 1;
var toggle = false;

if (mouseIsPressed && g === 1) {
  console.log('inside first `if`');
  toggle = true;
  console.log('set toggle =', toggle);
  g = 2;
  console.log('set g =', g);
}
if (mouseIsPressed && g === 2) {
  console.log('inside second `if`');
  toggle = false;
  console.log('set toggle =', toggle);
  g = 1;
  console.log('set g =', g);
}
```

You can see that both `if` statements are executed.

You want `else if` instead:

```
if (mouseIsPressed && g === 1) {
  toggle = true;
  g = 2;
} else if (mouseIsPressed && g === 2) {
  toggle = false;
  g = 1;
}
```

However, if you are not actually using `g` for anything else and just want to toggle the value of `toggle`, you can just do:

```
if (mouseIsPressed){
  toggle = !toggle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add and remove css classes:

```js
let toggle = false

document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (toggle) {
    document.getElementById("main").classList = "on"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("main").classList = "off"
  }
  const onOff = toggle ? "(off)" : "(on)"
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = onOff + " " + e.clientX + ", " + e.clientY
  toggle = !toggle
})
```

```css
#main {
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  height: 100px;
}

.on {
  background: blue;
}

.off {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```